# Why is this while loop not executing in my python code

Tags: python

I am trying to make a tic tac toe game in Python.  The instructor is saying to use a while loop to verify that the input is a number.  For some reason the while loop doesn't seem to be working. It is skipping the while loop and jumping straight to `return int(choice)`.  I tried to add an image but I'm not sure if it worked please let me know if you cannot see it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7uG6.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend new users visit [ask].  For your future reference, adding an image of a code is never preferred-- instead, add a [mcve] of your code as text in the body of the question.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: In addition with the mistake pointed in the answer with usage of str.isdigit() https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit is that in Python, comparison of boolean using == is discouraged https://pep8.org/#programming-recommendations instead use (if comparing to True) "while choice.isdigit()" or (if comparing to False) "while not choice.isdigit()"

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, it looks like you are checking if the built-in method `is_digit` is `False` in the while loop rather than the actual output of `is_digit()`. The only change should be changing your line 30 to be:

```
while choice.isdigit() == False:
```

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic way to enter the while loop would be like this:

```py
while not choice.isdigit():
    choice = input("Please enter a number (0-10): ")
```

This will produce `True` if `choice` is not integer and you will access the while loop and when the `choice` will be integer then `not choice.isdigit()` condition will be `False` and you will exit the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem arises in this line of your code -:

```
while choice.isdigit == False :
```

The problem is that you assume that what this condition does is, that it compares the result of the `isdigit` function executed on the choice variable to the False boolean on the right of the `==` operator.

But since you never called the function isdigit and only referenced it with a dot, what it compares is the function isdigit with the boolean False, which is never True, This makes the while loop not execute at all.
i.e. You do this -:

`while function == boolean : execute_my_code...`

While, what you need to do is -:

`while func_returned_boolean == boolean : execute_my_code...`

So what you just wanna do is call the function you referenced by adding two round open and close brackets[`()`] in front of the function name.
This calls the function and now what you compare is the function's returning bool value with the False boolean.

Like so -:

```
while choice.isdigit() == False : execute_my_code... # Instead of while choice.isdigit == False.
```

Also just as a suggestion and as pointed out by @Niel Godfrey Ponciano, since the return value of the `isdigit` function is a boolean nevertheless, it is more shorter to use the not keyword to check if it is not `True` i.e. If it is `False`, like so -:

```
while not choice.isdigit() : execute_my_code...
```

It saves a lot of your work to use the not keyword since you do not have to use the `== False` clause.